# Gib eine Nachricht ein vs Gib einen Text

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I have noticed that both seem to mean the same thing.

Is there a difference between them?

Comment: Probably one would not say one of these (missing object), but Text and Nachricht are used differently in some contexts (f.i. networking).

Comment: They are the same only in the meaning a *text* **can** be a *message*.

Comment: "Nachricht" means "Message" and "Text" means "Text". A message is usually a text but a text is not always a message.

Comment: Please but the actual question into the body of your post and use the title to describe what it is about.

Comment: Why did you accept the very answer that (currently) has -9 points??? :-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to your concrete question, if you want to say ***text me*** - ***send me a notice*** - ***drop me a message*** or something alike, you can say:

- schick / schreib mir eine Nachricht
- schick / schreib mir eine SMS/WhatsApp/etc... (more specific)

But there are the expressions ***inform me*** - ***notify me*** - ***let me know*** as well. Then you could say:

- gib mir Nachricht (*benachrichtigen* -
  http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Nachricht%20geben . Not used though)
- gib / sag mir Bescheid

It's not totally clear what the exact context is in your question, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

As commenters noted, "Nachricht" means "message" and "Text" means "text", so you would be able to use the two words interchangeably where you only expect a message to be entered (since you can only enter messages that consist of text.) It's the same in English though.